# Why can Cell in Rust only be used for Copy and not Clone types?

Tags: rust, traits

The documentation of the Rust standard library states that `Cell` can be only used for `Copy` types and that in all other cases one should use `RefCell`, but does not explain exactly why.

After studying the documentation and the code of both `Cell` and `RefCell`, the only point where it seems to be important is the `get` function of `Cell`. If the value is a `Copy` type then one can just return such a copy. But why is a clone not good enough?

One could directly implement the `set` function on top of `RefCell`:

```
fn set<T>(r: &RefCell<T>, v: T) {
    *r.borrow_mut() = v
}
```

This only works as long as no one else is holding a reference to the value. But if the value can be cloned, one can just do that:

```
fn get<T: Clone>(r: &RefCell<T>) -> T {
    r.borrow().clone()
}
```

Having a type like `Cell` working with `Clone` types would avoid the overhead of the run-time borrow checking. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Probably because `Clone` involves actually running *code*, and it can panic while it runs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's unsound. The comment by DK. is on the right track but you don't even need a panic to cause havoc. One problematic scenario is this:

1. Cells (together with `Option`) allow creating cycles, i.e., self-referential types
2. The `Clone` implementation gets a `&self` reference
3. In the presence of a cycle, the `Clone` implementation may thus access the cell that's being cloned
4. Therefore the object being cloned can overwrite itself, while it has an ordinary borrow to itself (namely, `&self`)
5. Overwriting while borrowing is unsound because it allows arbitrary type punning and other badness. For example, suppose there's `Result<T, E>` field that's initially `Ok(T)`, take a reference to the `T` inside and overwrite the `Result` with an `Err(R)`. Then the `&T` suddenly refers to an `E` value.

Credit for this example goes to Huon Wilson, see the user.rust-lang.org thread [Why does Cell require Copy instead of Clone?](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-does-cell-require-copy-instead-of-clone/5769/3). His write-up goes into more structural reasons for the restrictions and includes a complete code example, too.

Comment: Ah yes, I did not think about clone accessing the cell itself. And my set and get implementations from above avoid this as set cannot be called before get returns.

Comment: It seems to be the intuition should be simple. Rust disallows simultaneous sharing and mutation. `Cell` solves this by not providing a reference to the actual value (no sharing), but `.clone()` would take a reference as the argument.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is still completely correct (and fascinating), but I want to mention a few extra tools that `Cell` got in Rust 1.17, which don't require the contents to be `Copy`:

- `Cell::swap` exchanges the contents of two cells.
- `Cell::replace` puts a new value in a cell and returns the old value.
- `Cell::take` is like `replace`, using the `Default::default()` value.

Note the close parallel here with `mem::swap`, `mem::replace`, and `mem::take`. (Though actually the last one didn't get stabilized until Rust 1.40.) The `Cell` methods do effectively the same thing, but they work through shared references instead of requiring mutable ones.

For types that implement `Default`, we can use `Cell::take` to accomplish something very similar to `.clone()`, just with a few more steps:

```rust
fn clone_from_cell<T>(cell: &Cell<T>) -> T
where
    T: Clone + Default,
{
    let val: T = cell.take();
    let clone: T = val.clone();
    cell.set(val);
    clone
}
```

And for types that implement `Clone` but not `Default` (somewhat uncommon, but for example `NonZeroU32`), note that `Option<T>` implements `Default` regardless of `T`, so `Cell<Option<T>>` can be "cloned" using that function for any `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my opinion, but I can't tie it directly to a real reason that such a restriction exists.

I think of a copy as "cheap" (e.g. copying a handful of bits) and a clone as "expensive" (e.g. making a function call or changing data). If such a cell used `Clone`, it would *mandate* that the underlying value be duplicated on every use (`cell.get()`). For example, using a `CloneCell<Vec<T>>` would mean that every `cell.get()` would **require calling the memory allocator**. That's not a good idea.

Restricting to `Copy` types is thus potentially a way to guide people away from shooting themselves in the foot.

Comment: Yes, it is almost impossible that cloning on access would be faster than the dynamically checked borrowing, but I was looking for a setting, where things actually break.