# Could `Cell` in Rust be safely used on `Rc` specifically?

Tags: rust, clone, traits

It's been established (e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39667868/why-can-cell-in-rust-only-be-used-for-copy-and-not-clone-types#39673978)) that Rust's `Cell` is not usable for non-`Copy` types, because the `.get()` operation is only safe if it can guarantee that the process of cloning/copying the data out of the `Cell` is not going to be interrupted by something that assigns to the `Cell`.

The current restriction in Rust, therefore, is that `Cell.get()` is usable only if the type inside the cell is `Copy`; `Clone` is not enough, because there can't be any guarantee that the `.clone()` call doesn't somehow manage to access the `Cell` being cloned from and write to it while it's in the middle of being read. So code like this is illegal, because the compiler doesn't know for certain that `CloneableObject.clone()` doesn't do something absurd:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct CloneableObject {}

fn main() {
    let x = Cell::new(CloneableObject {});
    println!("{:?}", x.get());
}
```

My question is about the special case where the type wrapped by the `Cell` is the standard library type `Rc`. `Rc` is special in that `Rc.clone()` doesn't actually do any copying, and doesn't inspect the value that the `Rc` points to; it just increments an integer inside the `Rc`, something that can't possibly write to a `Cell` that contains an `Rc`.

Presumably, this would imply that code like the following could safely be legal:

```rust
use std::cell::Cell;
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let x = Cell::new(Rc::new(0i32));
    println!("{:?}", x.get());
}
```

However, it doesn't compile at present, because there isn't a special case for `Cell` together with `Rc`.

My question is: Is there any safety/soundness reason not to add such a special case for `Cell<Rc<T>>`? Or is this simply a case of "this would be perfectly safe, but we haven't taught the compiler how to recognise that it's safe yet"? (If doing this *would* be safe, I may submit it as a feature suggestion – it would be more efficient than `RefCell<Rc<T>>` due to not needing runtime checks – but want to make sure that there isn't some unsoundness that I'm missing.)

To avoid any confusion: I am intentionally asking about `Cell<Rc<T>>` in this question, not the more commonly used `Rc<Cell<T>>`/`Rc<RefCell<T>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it probably *could* be, but in its current state Rust lacks the specialization features needed to indicate that.

In theory, there could be a trait to indicate that a type is safe to clone from `Cell::get`:

```
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct Cell<T> {
    inner: UnsafeCell<T>,
}

impl<T> Cell<T> {
    pub fn set(&self, value: T) {
        unsafe { *self.inner.get() = value };
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> T
    where
        T: CellCloneable,
    {
        unsafe { *self.inner.get() }.clone()
    }
}

trait CellCloneable: Clone {}
impl<T> CellCloneable for T where T: Copy {}
impl<T> CellCloneable for Rc<T> {}
```

Unfortunately, this also doesn't compile also due to lacking specialization features.

And since the compiler cannot guarantee that an implementer doesn't end up calling `Cell::set` on itself, it'd have to be an `unsafe` trait. This trait would be very easy to get wrong: any dynamic dispatch would make this safety constraint impossible to guarantee and unrelated code could be updated to violate this constraint without using any `unsafe` itself.

IMO, this addition would go against `Cell`'s goal of being a fairly basic and safe primitive for interior mutability.

Comment: I did think of this implementation as a possibility (although to make it work in current Rust, you would need to call the method something like `get_clone`, and give it an (unsafe) trait bound that doesn't have a blanket implementation for `Copy`). There would be some ways you could make it harder to misuse by mistake, e.g. by giving the new trait its own method rather than reusing `Clone`. Alternatively, you could just write out `impl<T> Cell<Rc<t>>` directly, or even create a new type that acts like `Cell<Rc>`. I just wanted to verify that this would be safe before going down this route.